# How can I create a new theme for Mercurial or HgWeb?

Tags: mercurial, hgweb

I have a couple of Mercurial installations running on IIS7 on a 2008 server. I'd like to use the monoblue theme style for both of them, but I want to change the colour of the second one.

To accomplish this, I copied the monoblue theme, and it’s related static files and renamed it to monored. I adjusted the header.tmpl file to point at the new style-monored.css file in the static folder and updated the site's hgweb.config to reference my new theme, monored. I’ve done this in both the files in the site itself (in the template folder) and also in the Mercurial installation folder, C:\Program Files (x86)\Mercurial.

However, when I update the hgweb.config file, all that happens is that the theme reverts to paper (the default). I’m obviously missing something, but I can’t find any information on the web that points to what I’m missing out. Effectively, bar the change to the header.tmpl to reference the style-monored.css file in the static directory, the only other change I’ve made is to change the monoblue colour in the css file to a red variation i.e. #006699 became #996600.

Anyone out there got any ideas on what I’m missing out on changing. I’ve also investigated my Python installation to see if there were any Mercurial references in it, but I couldn’t find any.

FYI: My Python installation is from the Windows (x86) specific Python-2.7.5.msi
My Mercurial installation is from the Windows (x86) specific Mercurial 2.6.2 MSI installer.

In my travels about the Googlesphere, I’ve discovered the following two websites that have "instructions" on how to adjust/edit Mercurial templates. I’ve followed these, but to no avail.

http://www.endswithsaurus.com/2010/05/setting-up-and-configuring-mercurial-in_3404.html
http://colas.nahaboo.net/Hacks/HgwebMercurialTemplateCustomization

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

UPDATE: I found the answer to my question. All the template files I was making changes to are ignored by Mercurial. The correct template files to copy and edit are to be found in the \Python27\Lib\site-packages\mercurial\templates directory. I chanced upon this when I was re-reading my installation documentation on an unrelated matter.

Comment: Since you know the answer to your question you should either answer it yourself and accept it (that's allowed) or delete it.  Having it hang around as an unanswered question isn't so great.

Comment: I would have answered my own question. I did try to. Unfortunately my reputation wasn’t yet high enough for me to do so at the time. Editing the question was as close as I could get. I’ve apparently now gained enough reputation to be able to do so. Consider it done.

Comment: Awesome, welcome to the site. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question is that the template files that Mercurial references to modify the display are to be found in the `\Python27\Lib\site-packages\mercurial\templates` directory. I discovered this when I re-visited the documentation I'd created as I installed Mercurial onto my Windows 2008 R2 server.

Comment: A good way to find where the file that matter is is to run: `hg debug install` which includes a `templates` line.

Comment: Thanks Ry4an. A useful bit of info.

Comment: And, of course I had a typo in my comment.  debuginstall is one word.